# How to convert .net HMACMD5 hashing to php equivalent?

Tags: php, .net, vb.net, hash, md5

The .NET code I'm trying to convert to PHP is:

```
Dim hmac As New HMACMD5(secretPassword)
Dim computedHash As Byte() = hmac.ComputeHash(stringToHash)
```

Currently in php I am using:

```
$computedHash = hash_hmac('md5', $stringToHash, $secretPassword);
```

From what I understand the php function hash_hmac() is the correct function to use as that is how to specify to use md5, however in testing both cases produce different hash results. I understand the .net code returns an array, however the array values are completely different than the php results.

In the .net code there is ascii encoding on the parameters but I have already verified that my php code produces the same encoding results, only the hashing produces different results. I also tested encoding results regarding leading zeroes in two digit numbers ("021" vs "21"), yes they produce different encodings but that didn't solve the hash problem when I tried both.

Example vb .net variable values:

```
.NET ascii encoded secretPassword "pass123" = [112, 97, 115, 115, 49, 50, 51]
.NET ascii encoded stringToHash "hashstring" = [104, 97, 115, 104, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103] 
.NET hash results = [43, 65, 108, 137, 120, 163, 203, 231, 219, 197, 238, 187, 209, 216, 213, 225]
```

Php hash results (I already confirmed my encoding in php produces the same as .net):

```
a2c9f74f2597038a39b28538d7f1d73a
```

Comment: How about an example plaintext, hash, and secret from .NET? That way we can actually try to answer your question without guessing.

Comment: Updated, please see above, thx @Sammitch

Comment: Three things. First, show us your .NET code and your php code. Make it code that we can copy directly from your text, and compile and run. Second, show the exact output from your program. Finally, display the output from both programs in the same format. You'll find people much more willing to help out if they don't have to do the decimal-to-hex conversion in their heads. Make it easy for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, in case anyone comes across this:

If you are given example VB .NET code regarding API authentication and you see code that involves ASCII encoding your data and passwords into byte arrays, you do not need to do this step if you are trying to replicate the code in PHP.

PHP already inherently stores strings as byte arrays and they should already be in valid UTF-8 format. So basically skip any encoding step, simply plug in your params and go (params are strings):

```
$computedHash       = hash_hmac('md5', $strToHash, self::$password, true);
$computedHashString = base64_encode($computedHash);
```

You may need to change that last param to false depending on the api, but from what I'm told true is the most common scenario as api's generally expect the hash to be in binary then base 64 encoded. Hope this helped someone~